# ARIA + Angular: read text aloud on page load without stealing focus

Tags: javascript, angular, accessibility, wai-aria

We are writing an application using Angular (2+). What I am trying to do right now is ensure that a certain piece of text is read out loud when a page loads (or when a certain component on the page is re-created) without stealing focus, and without the text being read at any other time. The initial attempt was to add this to the top of the component:

```
<div
    class="a11y"
    aria-live="assertive">
  Content loaded
</div>
```

With `a11y` being a class to hide the text for sighted users. It does in fact read the text aloud when the component is created or re-created; unfortunately, it also reads the text aloud in other scenarios, such as when we do a router.navigateByUrl and cover the screen in a gray loading div. I also tried setting `aria-relevant=text` and swapping out the text in the component's `ngOnInit()` function, with no luck.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: So you don't want the text to be read when the text is updated? Can you just not update the text?

Comment: @sklingler93 The text is never actually changed, but it's read aloud when other things happen to the component (such as when the whole component is grayed out) and I'm trying to prevent that.

Comment: Can you wrap just the text in a div with `aria-live=assertive`?

Comment: @sklingler93 That was what we tried first; unfortunately, it keeps reading the text when we gray out the component.